# Does an uncountably infinite subset of the reals necessarily have an open interval subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have $S \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $S$ is uncountably infinite, is there necessarily a non-empty open subset $(a, b) \subseteq S$?

I feel like the answer is intuitively "yes", since if $S$ has no open interval subset then all its elements are "far enough apart" for there to be at most countably many of them in the real numbers. But I don't see a rigorous proof for the statement, and I'm still not even sure if the statement is true.

So is the statement true or not?

Comment: You would do well to read up on the Cantor set. About 95% of all mathematicians would have presumed this true before Cantor. That's the genius that Cantor was. Shame he was mentally affected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is false. The Cantor set provides an example of a set that contains no interval and yet, it is uncountable.

Comment: Even easier, take the irrationals as an example.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two immediate examples:
1). $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$. 
2). The standard Cantor set $C$.

And there are an awful lot more.